# Access denied While using phpmyadmin XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have installed XAMPP on windows 10 but cannot open phpMyAdmin. I had to change Apache port 443 to 4433 because of conflicts and now both apache and mysql are running. When I click on phpMyAdmin on my server it gives me the following message in a pink box:

MySQL said: Documentation

Cannot connect: invalid settings.
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

I've read the questions on similar problems but they mostly happened when someone changed the password, but for my case, the user is set to root and the password is empty both in MySQL server connection and in the config.inc.php file. I have no clue where to look for the problem.

Comment: check the mysql logs if there is an error. chakc also with the mysql client if you can open a connection the chech the phpmyadmin config file to see, if the right server is entered.

Comment: It sounds like your MySQL service isn't running; can you connect from the command line client? What does the XAMPP control panel show as the status for MySQL server?

Answer (score 0):

What version is your XAMPP? Try going to task manager, locate mysqlI and end task. Now close the XAMPP window and open it again. Go to Mysql and try test the connection by connecting to the database on port 3306. If it gives en error check the error log in the XAMPP.